# Makefile: generic way to indccate all available .info file from one folder to lcov

Tags: code-coverage, gnu-make, lcov

I'm working on some tests and I'm using lcov
In order to correctly manage the coverage of all tests, my makefile:

1. compile each test
2. launch the test
3. generate the .info file using `geninfo`
4. delete *.gcda, *.gcno

When this is made for all tests, I want to generate the whole coverage by calling:
`lccov --add-tracefile <name>.info -o global_coverage.info`

However, it seems that I need to indicate all .info file by `--add-tracefile <name>.info`

Ex: if I've `file1.info` and `file2.info`, I need to call:
`lccov --add-tracefile file1.info --add-tracefile file2.info -o global_coverage.info`

I can retrieve the list of all .info file by

```
# Get all .info file for coverag
INFO_FILES = $(wildcard $(TEST_BUILD_DIR)/*.info)
```

Is there a generic way to call this `lcov` tool by indicating all .info file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
# Get all .info file for coverag
INFO_FILES := $(wildcard $(TEST_BUILD_DIR)/*.info)

global_coverage.info: $(INFO_FILES)
        lccov $(addprefix --add-tracefile ,$^) -o $@
```